# How to make the yuicompressor jar file a singleton, or globally accessible?

Tags: windows, yui, cygwin, yui-compressor

I'd like to put the [yuicompressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor) jar file in a single folder so that I can call

`java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar ...`

from anywhere on my system, with cygwin. For bash files I use I simply put them in a common folder, and added the folder's path to my windows user's PATH environment variable and the bash commands were found in cygwin.

when I `echo $PATH` I see the folder I put the yuicompressor jar into listed in the $PATH..

But when I try `java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar myfile.js -o myfile-min.js` (for example) I get the following error message:

> Unable to access jarfile yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar

Even when I try providing an absolute path to the jarfile I get the same error message..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH` environment variable is a list of directories the shell will search through in an attempt to run a command.

`java.exe` **will not** search the directories on the `PATH` environment variable to try and locate the archive you are attempting to run. So running `java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar` from any directory other than the one containing the archive would be expected to fail.

What is the full command you are attempting when providing an absolute path?

Comment: "What is the full command you are attempting when providing an absolute path?" java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar myfile.js -o myfile-min.js

Comment: That's not an absolute path to the archive. (I'm after exactly what you're using in your absolute path call because I would expect to see an absolute path work.)

Comment: an absolute path is what I'm trying to avoid, so I don't know what you mean when you ask 
"What is the full command you are attempting when providing an absolute path?". I'm not attempting to use a absolute path because I don't want to use an absolute path.. You'll have to clarify your meaning.

Comment: I'm was after the full command you entered when using an absolute path, e.g. `java -jar C:\path\to\yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar myfile.js -o myfile-min.js`.

I'm assuming you want to avoid the absolute path because you don't want to have to type the full path out when running the command? I have an idea for a solution that wouldn't require entering the full path at your prompt, but would require the absolute path to be entered in a shell script. But this is no good if the command with an absolute path fails as well. Hence I want to work out why the absolute path isn't working.

Comment: C:\www\erikvold.com\js>java -jar C:\commands\yucompressor-2.4.2.jar string.js -o
 test-min.js
Unable to access jarfile C:\commands\yucompressor-2.4.2.jar

Comment: Looks right to me. Maybe you've got a permissions issue? I tried setting the file permissions on the archive so I didn't have access to it and ran the command again, and got the "Unable to access jarfile" message. Try running an independent command on the file, something like `cat C:\commands\yucompressor-2.4.2.jar` and see what happens to confirm/eliminate it being a file permissions issue.